# Remove column value after '-' in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, substring

I new and learning SQL with small data set. I'm using SQL Server, trying to clean up the data.

I have column with values like this:

| Job_title |
| --- |
| STAFF ENGINEER-SOFTWARE |
| Programmer Analyst -IT |
| Analyst Communication Systems [KBGFJG68718-2] |

Expected result should be like the table below, here I am trying to remove special characters, numbers and roman letters.

| Job_title |
| --- |
| STAFF ENGINEER |
| Programmer Analyst |
| Analyst Communication Systems |

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide sample code?

Comment: You are describing multiple replacement operations here.  Are these the _only_ types of cleanup which you need to do here?

Comment: Using MSSQL. using REPLACE(JOB_TITLE,'%[^a-Z0-9, ]%','') function ,but for the above  result i haven't tried anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Find the first character that is neither letter nor blank nor digit. You can use `PATINDEX` for this.
2. If such character is found, take the string until there and remove trailing blanks. Else take the whole string.

The query:

```
select
  case when patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', job_title) > 0 then
    rtrim(substring(job_title, 1, patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', job_title) - 1))
  else
    job_title
  end as job
from mytable;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab1d7bd0890530c55ced09457f532136

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, the query works .